# Prompt user to update app if there is a newer version

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Is there a way using nativescript or is there a plugin to check if the app that is running is the current version, and if not prompt the user to update their app?

Comment: Did you check https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-store-update

Comment: Thanks for that. I can't seen to figure it out. If I download the git repo, I can't seem to get the demo to run. If I add it to the project I am trying to get it to work in, I can't seem to get it to prompt me if I change the version to an older version in my plist.info